# Empty dataframe boxplot...WHY?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

In my script, I've a class in charge of producing plots from a dataframe. Each column of the dataset is full of integers and there is just a column, named 'CLASS', that represents the category of each row. Let's say, for convenience, that there are only 2 string values: `True` and `False`. So, for a specified column, I create a new temporary dataframe with just the series of interesting values. I tested if `NaN` values are present and the answer is no: the main dataframe and, by extension, the temporary one are complete (both tested). So, I just ran the code below but each file is empty.

```
def draw_box_plot(self, title: str, column):

        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.title(title + '_' + column)
        temp = pd.DataFrame({column: self.df[column], 'CLASS': self.df['CLASS']})
        temp.boxplot(by='CLASS')
        fig.savefig(self.path + '_'+column+'_boxplot.svg', format="svg")
```

I tried different things (subplots, specify boxplot `return_type='axes'`) but nothing happens. Can you spot what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you try using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)` and `temp.boxplot(by="CLASS", ax=ax)`. Does that work?

Comment: IT WORKED, can you explain me how this thing works?